# Обновление ListView , когда пользователь прокручивает его

Tags: java, android, listview

Необходимо постоянно обновлять список чатов в `ListView` и этот список пользователь может постоянно прокручивать.
Обновление делаю в

```
  private TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(isLoading) return;

            arrayChat.clear();

            loadChatList(((BaseActivity)getActivity()).login, ((BaseActivity)getActivity()).key, limit,0,"");
        }
    };
```

Вся проблема в `arrayChat.clear()`. Если пользователь в данный момент прокручивает список, то на этой строчке появляется ошибка `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 58, Size: 0`.

Как можно это попроще обыграть если не делать функцию, которая будет обновлять список без обнуления? Или без этой функции не обойтись?

Comment: А почему вообще выбран ListView? Его вообще лучше не использовать, а тем более, когда есть слово "ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ". Вместо ListView уже лучше использовать новый виджет - RecyclerView.

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже давно пора. Перепишу.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось проще написать следущее))

```
int index = arrayChat.indexOf(chat);
    if(index>-1)
    {
        if(index!=j) {
            arrayChat.remove(chat);
            arrayChat.add(j, chat);
        }
    }
    else
        arrayChat.add(chat);
```

Всем спасибо.